# The definition of ${}^{\circ} \mathcal{HT}^{\mathcal{D}\text{-}\Theta^{\pm \mathscr{ell}}}$ in Inter-universal Teichmüller theory

Tags: ct.category-theory, set-theory, arithmetic-geometry

I am reading Mochizuki's INTER-UNIVERSAL TEICHMÜLLER THEORY I to III and I hardly understand this theory, but there is a thing particularly I bother.
Given an [initial $\Theta$-data](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/initial+%CE%98-data), consider $\mathcal{D}\text{-}\Theta^{\pm \mathscr{ell}}$ Hodge theaters $\mathcal{HT}^{\mathcal{D}\text{-}\Theta^{\pm \mathscr{ell}}}$ defined in [IUtchI Definition 6.13(2)](https://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/%7Emotizuki/Inter-universal%20Teichmuller%20Theory%20I.pdf) and a poly isomorphism $\Xi$ between them(i.e. a set of isomorphisms between two $\mathcal{D}\text{-}\Theta^{\pm \mathscr{ell}}$ Hodge theaters). Following this, let $\{{}^{m} \mathcal{HT}^{\mathcal{D}\text{-}\Theta^{\pm \mathscr{ell}}}\}_m$ be an infinite sequence depicted as follows (actually this is a part of a log-theta lattice though, I simplify by thinking only column):
\begin{array}{rrcl}
\cdots \xrightarrow{\Xi} {}^{-1}\mathcal{HT}^{\mathcal{D}\text{-}\Theta^{\pm \mathscr{ell}}}\ \xrightarrow{\Xi} {}^{0} \mathcal{HT}^{\mathcal{D}\text{-}\Theta^{\pm \mathscr{ell}}}\ \xrightarrow{\Xi} {}^{1}\mathcal{HT}^{\mathcal{D}\text{-}\Theta^{\pm \mathscr{ell}}}\ \xrightarrow{\Xi} \cdots
\end{array}
In [IUtchIII Proposition 3.10](https://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/%7Emotizuki/Inter-universal%20Teichmuller%20Theory%20III.pdf), he introduces ${}^{\circ} \mathcal{HT}^{\mathcal{D}\text{-}\Theta^{\pm \mathscr{ell}}}$ for the $\mathcal{D}\text{-}\Theta^{\pm \mathscr{ell}}$ Hodge theater determined up to isomorphism. It seems that this *isomorphism* is $\Xi$ according to the context, but however, as far as I know, *an object determined up to isomorphism* should represent the isomorphic class. That is, since [isomorphism is an equivalence relation](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Isomorphism_is_Equivalence_Relation) it is supposed to mean the equivalence class by regarding the isomorphism as an equivalence relation. Especially since such isomorphism is a relation, it must be a subset of $source \times target$ of the isomorphism, but $\Xi$ is clearly not because it is a set of isomorphisms. Therefore I feel ${}^{\circ} \mathcal{HT}^{\mathcal{D}\text{-}\Theta^{\pm \mathscr{ell}}}$ can't be defined and [Proposition 3.10](https://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/%7Emotizuki/Inter-universal%20Teichmuller%20Theory%20III.pdf) does not make sense. Is this a mistake that is based on a lack of my comprehension? If you could answer me, I would be very happy. Thanks in advance.

EDIT :
I am sorry I didn't explain it clearly enough. Please let me explain my thinking by using a toy model of vector spaces. Defining an isomorphism class, as is usually done, should mean the following manipulation: Let $Vect$ be the set of all vector spaces(of course this is the proper class though, I'll leave the details out.) we define the sets $\sim$ as $\{ (V_1, V_2): V_1 \cong V_2\}$. Trivially since $\sim \subset Vect \times Vect$ this is the [(binary) relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_relation#Definition) on $Vect$(Here I adopted the set-theoretic definition as there is in the link,) and also, [equivalence relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation#Definition) as well(one can prove this by using properties of isomorphism.) Therefore, one can define the [isomorphism class](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/isomorphism+class) of a vector space $V$ by $\sim$ as $[V]:= \{V' \in Vect: V' \sim V \}$. On the other hand, however, if we replace $\sim$ with a poly isomorphism $\Xi$, then how can we define an isomorphism class? The first thing we need to do is, to define a relation $\{ (V_1, V_2): \phi(V_1, V_2) \}$. That is, we need to find a formula $\phi(V_1, V_2)$ using the set of isomorphisms $\Xi$. It seems to me that this is not obvious. For example, if we consider $\phi(V_1, V_2)$ as "$|\Xi| > 0$", then this is (from the definition of isomorphicness between two objects) the same as the above relation so meaningless. Hence, the definition of an isomorphism class(in other words *an object determined up to isomorphism*) using $\Xi$ does not make sense(I think this cannot be solved even if one shifts the mathematical foundation from ZFC to another one.) I think Mochizuki's definition of ${}^{\circ} \mathcal{HT}^{\mathcal{D}\text{-}\Theta^{\pm \mathscr{ell}}}$ is under the same circumstance. Are there any mistakes in my thinking? If so, I would appreciate it if you could tell me.

Comment: Isomorphisms are only subsets of the cartesian product in one specific foundation. In others they are not. The mathematics here should really **not** depend on whether one uses ZFC or a structural foundation like ETCS+R. Mochizuki's uses of category theory, and in particular his ideas around "objects up to isomorphism" are rather non-standard, and in my eyes misleading.

Comment: @DavidRoberts Thank you for your comment again (following my past question)! Actually, I am not much familiar with the foundations of mathematics, but my comprehension is the following: as you said, for example, I think one on the HoTT+Univalence axiom doesn't think of isomorphisms as subsets of the cartesian product, on the other hand, others on the ZFC(if necessary, plus the existence of large cardinals) think of such(and I am on ZFC and consider all mathematical objects as a set). However, I have thought this fact doesn't solve what can't be defined in ZFC.

Comment: My understanding has been that if it could be defined on HoTT+Univalence axiom etc., it could always be translated (with additional axioms if necessary) as a definition in ZFC and vice versa, and hence, the definition that doesn't work on ZFC(even with additional axioms if necessary, again) doesn't work on other foundation as well. Is this wrong?

Comment: You don't need to go to such details. The actual encoding of functions in any foundation should have no impact on mathematics outside of actual foundational questions, like "is this function definable in an axiom system with such-and-such restricted quantifier complexity?" and the such like. So questions that involve thinking of isomorphisms as subsets of the cartesian product are not useful to try to unpack what is being claimed, here.

Comment: In this situation, in a sense evidently, the definition that relations are a certain subset of a cartesian product, means what ${}^{\circ} \mathcal{HT}^{\mathcal{D}\text{-}\Theta^{\pm \mathscr{ell}}}$ doesn't go well, I think. My opinion is: as I wrote in my question, I think this object must be supposed to be the equivalence class by the equivalence relation $\Xi$. However, since $\Xi$ is a set of isomorphisms and so this is obviously even not a binary relation on $\mathcal{D}\text{-}\Theta^{\pm \mathscr{ell}}$ Hodge theaters. Therefore, the definition of this object doesn't make sense.

Comment: May I ask what your background is? The kind of detail you are providing makes me suspect that you are not far past learning things like equivalence classes and so on, but I apologise if this is mistaken. On a website for mathematics researchers, you really don't need to clarify what you mean by an binary relation by giving a link to a definition.

Comment: Thank you very much for your patience with my question. As a matter of fact, I have already graduated from a mathematics department of a university in a not-so-famous country, and I have already studied equivalence relations, etc. The reason I am posting links to binary relations, etc. is to specify that I am thinking of binary relations as a set here, but I am sorry if this is unnecessary.

Comment: OK. It's just that it seems like some of the confusions are coming from ideas that are much more preliminary that the complicated mess that Mochizuki built. You really shouldn't need to try to formally define as a set or class, in some chosen foundation, what you mean by the equivalence relation that defines equivalence classes. It would be like doing number theory research, and specifying how integers multiply by talking about the multiplication table as done in school maths. It's now how the matter proceeds. I'm not sure what to advise you here apart from that IUT might not be worth it?

Comment: In particular, Mochizuki has acknowledged that a lot of the stuff in his IUT papers is needlessly general, and other people who have tried to make sense of it, for instance Taylor Dupuy, managed to write down bits of hypothetical mathematics that use standard mathematical definitions and objects, and very little trace of all the increasingly novel and baroque constructions of Mochizuki, while possibly and apparently capturing what was intended. If we knew for sure, we wouldn't “... have the ridiculous situation where ABC is a theorem in Kyoto but a conjecture everywhere else”—Frank Calegari.

Comment: I got it. I don't know if this is my lack of ability, my philosophical position, or my personality, but for example, I cannot say that a polynomial ring $R[X]$ exists if I don't know what kind of set the indeterminate element $X$ is(By the way, I find the definition of an indeterminate element as a set on page 97 of Lang's Algebra.) But at the same time, I understand that many people discuss about polynomials without being aware of what kind of set the indeterminate element $X$ is. Is that what you mean by "It's now how the matter proceeds."?

Comment: No one in number theory or commutative algebra worries what set underlies the ring $R[X]$ any more than they worry what underlying set the natural numbers have. There's a famous paper "What numbers could not be" https://www.jstor.org/stable/2183530 that pushes back against the idea that numbers "are" sets. Before set theory, people did lots of amazing mathematics, and even today, most people don't even think much about set theory. It's like worrying about the underlying machine code CPU-level algorithm when trying to write a CSS style sheet.

Comment: And mathematics can be entirely founded in type theory (not HoTT, even simpler than that), and there's not a set in sight, and everything is just syntax.

Comment: I just had a quick look at Thorsten Altenkirch's "[Should Type Theory Replace Set Theory as the Foundation of Mathematics?](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10516-023-09676-0)" before and he stated, "When saying Type Theory we mean HoTT." I assumed that "Type Theory" in the context of the comparison with ZFC meant "HoTT", but I'm sorry if I'm wrong.

Comment: Anyway, My philosophical position is, many programmers don't focus on what is CPU used, but there surely is there. Between you and me used CPU may be different though, CSS has compatibility and is implemented in some way. If not, there is no the CSS style sheet. Of course, although historically mathematics had been developed without any CPUs, I think the discovery that "mathematics is on a CPU" itself is now an immutable mathematical fact just like the Pythagorean theorem to unchanged.

Comment: In any case, I understood this is a philosophical question rather than a mathematical one. I appreciate your patience gets you to post many great comments.

Comment: There are lots of different sorts of type theory, so you can forgiven if you're not familiar with them all! Especially as it's not your foundation of choice. :-) I hope it's helpful, and not discouraging.